# Is it possible to implement init.php in my wordpress plugin.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, block, wordpress-gutenberg

So I'm developing a Wordpress plugin, and I'd like to include the code from the init.php file to my plugin.php file.

My plugin does contain a working hook:
require_once plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) . '/src/init.php';

To be exact this is a wordpress gutenberg block plugin. I have used this project to start: 
https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block

So as I have asked above, is there a way to implement the code inside my plugin.php file? And if so, how?

I'd like to achieve this, so my src folder would only contain files that have either .js or .css extension and to store anything plugin related php code in one file.